# How to Delete a record in a subform when you click a button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm getting a run time error `3131` Syntax error in `FROM` clause.  Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

```
Dim strSQL
If Not (Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
strSQL = "Delete * FROM PlantTransactionQuery" & _
"WHERE TransactionID=" & Me![TransactionID] & Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Recordset.Fields("TransactionID")
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me.PlantTransactionQuery.Form.Requery
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using SQL statements to delete records unless there is truly no other option.

Can you put the button on the subform itself? I think all subforms, except datasheet views, allow you to have buttons on them. Then just run the normal code to delete a record.

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
```

**Edit1:**
Since you are using a Datasheet view you have basically two options.

1) The datasheet view provides a right-click menu to delete records if you go to the far left for the row.

2) Your other option is to create a public function on the subform that runs the code I listed above and then call it from the main form when the user clicks your button on your main form.

Comment: Nope it wont work because you cant put a button for each record in a datasheet im not using VisualStudio im using Access 2007 but thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Your original question doesn't say what kind of form you're trying to use. My reply has nothing to do with visual studio.

Comment: @HK1. I'm interested as to why you don't recommend using SQL to delete records? I use them regularly, but normally on unbound forms. With a simple confirmation box and some validation they seem safe to me?

Comment: I was assuming you were talking about bound forms. When you use SQL statements on bound forms you bypass the many different features and events of the form. Users might end up seeing rows with #DELETED in them. Or read/write errors if they delete a record they were editing.

Comment: I'm getting a run time error 3131 Syntax error in FROM clause. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: You're trying to delete using a Query name in the From Clause. I don't recommend performing Deletes on a query. Always put table names in the From clause. If there are multiple tables then you should several delete queries or else use "Cascade Deletes" on your relationship.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the SQL statement is there is no separator (space or line break) between `PlantTransactionQuery` and `WHERE`.  I shortened the string to make it more obvious.

```vb
strSQL = "Delete * FROM PlantTransactionQuery" & _
"WHERE TransactionID="
```

Add this line to your code immediately after you build the string.

```vb
Debug.Print strSQL
```

Then you can go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to examine the statement you're asking the db engine to execute.  If the problem is not apparent, copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the SQL string is missing a space between the table name and the WHERE clause. The current statement (...PlantTransactionQuery" & _ "WHERE TransactionID="...) will result in a SQL string that will look like this: "Delete * FROM ***PlantTransactionQueryWHERE*** TransactionID=" & [parameters]. Access will not be able to find a table called ***PlantTransactionQueryWHERE***.
To correct this issue, just add a space either between the table name and the quotation marks (...PlantTransactionQueryWHERE " & _) or before the WHERE clause (" WHERE...).

Comment: please consider formatting the code in your answer following the help section of the edit dialog